# How to make text field flow to the top of the screen when the user starts typing and show list of results underneath the text field?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to create an text field which will flow to the top of the screen when the user starts typing and will show results in a list beneath it. I'm already gathering the results matching the users query into a list from Firebase, all I need is to somehow display the data. I would like to have the search results displayed under the text field in a similar way as google play is showing the search history. Any ideas witch widget should I use, so it would pop under the text field when the user starts typing?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this package ([material_floating_search_bar](https://pub.dev/packages/material_floating_search_bar)) to obtain this behavior.